# Same settings in shader editor, yet different outcome

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I tried to make a donut based on BlenderGuru's YouTube video, however, despite the settings are identical, I still do get a different result... below is his work, and the next one is mine... Could anyone share a little bit on this?

[image: BlenderGuru's Donut]

[image: My Donut]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like though you have displacement connected, it is not enabled (hence why the edges of your mesh seem perfectly "round"). To use displacement properly, you must enable it in the material settings (It's in 2 places - confusing, I know). It's under *Material Properties > Settings > Surface > Displacement*. Change it from "Bump Only" to "Displacement Only" or "Bump and Displacement".

[image: Displace]